# ListView not fit in bottom when using CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, listview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I use different Fragments in my app. Ones fragments contain RecyclerView and others contain ListView and GridView. But ListView and GridView not fit in bottom screen. How to fix this? Thx.

P.S: Sorry for my English.

[image]

**ActivityLayout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:elevation="0dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/app_nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**TabsLayout:**

```
<ViewFlipper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/flipper"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<include
    layout="@layout/layout_please_wait"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

<include
    layout="@layout/layout_no_internet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</ViewFlipper>
```

**TabLayout:**

```
<ViewFlipper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/flipper"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    layout="@layout/layout_please_wait" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/grid_padding"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/grid_padding">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/dateSpiner"
        style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/spinner_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/billboardList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:columnWidth="@dimen/grid_item_column_width"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/grid_horizontal_spacing"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/grid_vertical_spacing">

    </GridView>
</LinearLayout>

<include
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    layout="@layout/layout_no_internet" />

</ViewFlipper>
```

Answer (score 1):

With `com.android.support:design:25.0.1`, I experienced a similar problem where bottom of view would not scroll up completely when using `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and `NestedScrollView`. The problem disappeared when device was rotated or by opening/closing keyboard, which to me indicates a support lib bug.

I solved it by fiddling with a view to trigger some refresh of fragment.

In `onViewCreated` I added

```
 Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mSomeViewInsideNestedScrollView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mSomeViewInsideNestedScrollView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
```

to put actions at the end of UI thread queue.

I realize this looks like an ugly hack, but it solved my problem.